# How Can I Choose Appropriate ComboBox Value Based on Select ListView Record? - C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

[http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/9417/snapshotapp.jpg http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/9417/snapshotapp.jpg](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/9417/snapshotapp.jpg)

Contact Title has a default value which is Sales Person. Anyhow, when a user
click Edit on the chosen ListView record, i need Contact Title to have
the right value that corresponds to the chosen record. For example,
if user clicks edit, the fields on the left side will be filled with
values. In this case, i want Contact Title to view the right value.

How can i do it?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've retrieved the text from the list just use it to find the correct record in the `ComboBox` as:

```
cbo.SelectedIndex = cbo.FindStringExact("Sales Person")
```